# Как правильно: «терминология экстремизма» или «терминология по вопросу экстремизма»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология, выбор-варианта

Если речь идет о совокупности таких терминов в уголовном кодексе, как "экстремизм", "экстремистская деятельность" (группа, организация, подготовка), "экстремистский материал", то можно ли ее назвать терминологией экстремизма?

Или это неправильно? В Национальном корпусе есть такие примеры:
словарь-справочник «Терминология нефтяного бизнеса»;
терминология стандартных обвинений;
терминология сотрудников местного МВД;
терминология групповщины;
военная терминология в художественной прозе;
геодезическая терминология.

Тогда можно из этих примеров сделать вывод, что "терминология экстремизма" — это терминология, присущая экстремистам. Но в уголовном кодексе, может быть, речь идет о терминологии борьбы с экстремизмом или о чем-то в этом роде.

Или так: терминология в сфере борьбы с экстремизмом?
И как тогда назвать эту терминологию?

Comment: терминология вопросов экстремизма, терминология в вопросах экстремизма

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд,  *экстремизм* - тоже термин, обозначающий понятие и требующий строгого определения. С ним могут быть связаны другие термины (вторичные, подчинённые), используемые при его изучении или решении связанных с проявлениями Э. проблем. Назвать совокупность этих терминов по аналогии с прочими "измами", обозначающими области человеческой деятельности (научное направление, политическое течение и пр.), не представляется возможным: простейший вариант ("терминология экстремизма") может, как вы правильно заметили, ассоциироваться с жаргоном неких "экстремистов". Я бы предложил такой вариант: "**терминология, связанная с понятием экстремизма**".